# SAP Crystal reports (Failed to load database information)

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports-2010

favorite

There is a problem i have been facing for couple of days. The problem is that i have developed C# Winform application using windows 7 professional sp1,mysql5.5 and SAP crystal report. When i deploy... and install it on the client machine then if the application finds windows 7 professional sp1 on client machine the reports are displayed very well in the application but if it finds (other than windows 7 sp1) professional on the client machine it gives error "Failed to load database information. bla bla {GUID}.rpt file" while displaying or printing. The application developed is not working on other than (Windows 7 professional sp1).

Deploying includes packages. .NET frame work 4.0 , Run time Crystal report Engine , Mysql 5.5 and VS C++ Redistributable.

Developer Machine has. Windows 7 professional sp1, Visual Studio 2010 , SAP Crystal Report for VS 2010, MYSQL Server 5.5

Answer (score 0):

your application  EXE file cannot stand alone to running it, the EXE file need the [app_name].exe.config in the same directory so the application can run and load the crystal report successfully.

so these is my conclusion:

1. the app.exe.config is all in one package which cannot be separated with the EXE file.
2. the supporting component such as dll files, app.exe.config etc CANNOT be combined into the EXE file.

You can find more in following [Link](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3200344)

Try this also:

Add the following section to the config file:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
 <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

The attribute will be required to view reports based on ADO.NET objects

Comment: I have associated all the reference files actually my means is that when i install it on client machine and it finds windows 7 it displays and print very well. But if it finds other window 7 then it gives prescribed error.

Comment: I have used already it in the Application.exe.config file.  (Actually my first create a dataset then put data to XML file and save it D:/ and crystal report pick XML as data source file(database file).

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and lost many time to look up, searching and try till since when I install Crystal Service Pack 39 (32 bit)  and It was resolved.

I think you can try to install the last service pack of SAP Crystal report.